# Im trying to learn child and parent process for C language

Tags: c, parent-child

I have written down this code to show the process id of each child and parent as well as the change of variable. a and b is getting the correct values but the parent and child is not getting a unique process id. I have tried to change the order of the child and parent and it shows the same issue. can someone explain how to properly show the child and parent that gives different PID?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int a = 10, b = 25, fq, fr;
fq = fork(); 
if(fq == 0){ 
    a = a + b;
    printf("Process Q(child): The value of a = %d\n, value b = %d\n, and the pid = %i\n", a, b, getpid());
    fr = fork(); 
    if (fr != 0){ 
        b = b + 20;
        printf("Process R(parent): The value of a = %d\n, value b = %d\n, and the pid = %i\n", a, b, getpid()); 
    }
    else{ 
            a = (a * b) + 30;
            printf("Process R(child): The value of a = %d\n, value b = %d\n, and the pid = %i\n", a, b, getpid());
        }
}
else{
    b = a + b - 5;
    printf("Process Q(parent): The value of a = %d\n, value b = %d\n, and the pid = %i\n", a, b, getpid()); 
}
return 0;
```

}

the output i received is:

```
Process Q(parent): The value of a = 10
, value b = 30
, and the pid = 8141
Process Q(child): The value of a = 35
, value b = 25
, and the pid = 8142
Process R(parent): The value of a = 35
, value b = 45
, and the pid = 8142
Process R(child): The value of a = 905
, value b = 25
, and the pid = 8143
```

the output I theoretically should have gotten is

```
Process Q(parent): The value of a = 10
, value b = 30
, and the pid = 8141
Process Q(child): The value of a = 35
, value b = 25
, and the pid = 8142
Process R(parent): The value of a = 35
, value b = 45
, and the pid = 8143
Process R(child): The value of a = 905
, value b = 25
, and the pid = 8144
```

EDIT: It was right the whole time. I just didnt understand the concept of it. Check the answer for the reason why.

Comment: `but the parent and child is not getting a unique process id.` What? Can you add your output - and the output you did expect - to the question?

Comment: sorry i forgot to write the output i obtained. please see the edit in a few minutes. 
Edit: finish adding the output and what i theoretically should have gotten

Comment: `the output I theoretically should have gotten is` You fork twice, for a total of three processes. There can't be four PIDs in three processes.

Comment: To elaborate on tkausl's comment: Q(child) and R(parent) are the same process.

Comment: The child process from the first call to `fork` is the parent process of the second call to `fork`.

Comment: hmm wouldnt 2 forks mean 4 process id? the first if statement is the child then the else statement becomes the parent?? unless its because i did a
if(...){
  .....
   if{(...){
        ....

Comment: A fork creates *one* new process and keeps the original process in tact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is correct. You have 2 forks but 4 printfs

```
fq = fork(); 
if(fq == 0){ 
    a = a + b;
    printf(pid of proc 1: 8142);
    fr = fork(); 
    if (fr != 0){ 
        b = b + 20;
        printf(pid of proc 2: 8143); 
    }
    else{ 
            a = (a * b) + 30;
            printf(pid of proc 1: 8142); <<< agan, you are still in the process 1
        }
}
else{
    b = a + b - 5;
    printf(Main process: 8141); 
}
```

Since processes run in parallel, there is no guarantee in which order the messages are printed out (besides the relative order of messages in process 2). I think that 8141 belongs to the main process, whil 8143 belongs to the process 1. You can verify it by the values printed. However, the string output is line-buffered and lines might come in orbitrary order as well.